# Using regex in Vb.net to extract phone numbers

Tags: html, regex, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I wrote this code to extract mobile numbers from web link
basically i got three links in list box and getting its source code using the code below
now while i'm trying to use RegEx to Extract Phone Number but i'm getting same number again and again.
This is full code which i wrote! and the website from i'm extracting link is

http://bolee.com/nf/all-results

```
Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please Extract Links First")
    Else
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ScrapLinks()
End Sub



Private Function ScrapLinks()
    Dim hw As New HtmlWeb()
    Try
        doc = hw.Load(TextBox1.Text)
        doc.LoadHtml(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='ad_list']").InnerHtml())

        For Each link As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")

            Dim hrefValue As String = link.GetAttributeValue("href", String.Empty)

            If hrefValue.Contains("/detail/") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(hrefValue)
            End If
        Next

        Dim items(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As Object
        ListBox1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0)
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items.AsEnumerable().Distinct().ToArray())
        lbllinks.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error " + ex.Message)

    End Try
    Return Nothing

End Function
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
        Dim re As New Regex("(\+92|0092)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}|\d{11}|\d{4}-\d{7}")

        ' For Each link As String In ListBox1.Items

        Dim hw As New HtmlWeb()
        doc = hw.Load(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        Dim data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='det_ad f_left']").InnerText

        '    For Each match As Match In re.Matches(data)

        TextBox2.Text = Data


        '    Next
        'Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error " + ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is s sample of out put i'm getting

03152405552
03152405552
03152405552
03152405552
03152405552
03152405552

Comment: your regex seems to be fine. Can you put your input data?

Comment: yes! can i upload image over here or what?

Comment: Just edit and add some sample plain text.

Comment: Seems odd that the escapes are not escaped in the double quoted string.

Comment: Means? should i add the type output in double quotes.

Comment: What is the sample _input_ ?

Comment: Does your list box selected item need to be changing? It looks like you loop for each link, but do not change the selected item in the list box.

Comment: my list box items are changing,

Comment: Your regex works fine: http://regex101.com/r/pA9bE4/1. I think your problem is on the line: `Dim data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='det_ad f_left']").InnerText`. Have you debugged `data` to ensure that your data is being updated?

Comment: Maybe you need to do a Match.next kind of thing. I don't know vb just wondering.

Comment: its also fetching the same text

Comment: So the selected item is probably not needed. See if the control gives you a next in list func.

Comment: Checkout my full code which i updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code instead:

```
Try

    For Each link As String In ListBox1.Items
        Listbox1.SelectedIndex += 1
        Dim hw As New HtmlWeb()
        doc = hw.Load(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        Dim data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='det_ad f_left']").InnerText

        For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(data, "(\+92|0092)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}|\d{11}|\d{4}-\d{7}")
            TextBox2.Text += vbNewLine & match.Value
        Next
    Next

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error " + ex.Message)

End Try
```

The idea is to create a new regex on each new input data to avoid having any cache.

Comment: Bro checkout my full code and the link which i wrote in my question i've edited it!

Comment: @BestNewspk unfortunately I don't know Vb. But did you try my approach? Use this line instead of yours `For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(data, "(\+92|0092)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}|\d{11}|\d{4}-\d{7}")`

Comment: yes i tried its working fine but going faster then it should when i'm clicking on the listbox item it goes down directly

Comment: @BestNewspk sorry I'm not clear. Did my answer answer to your question?

Comment: It's gives me little help :)